# How To Implement jQuery File Upload Plugin in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp-2.3, jquery-file-upload

I am trying to use jQuery File Upload plugin in my CakePHP project downloaded from [JqueryFileUpload - CakePHP](https://github.com/hugodias/FileUpload)

My problem is that, I am only able to follow the directions as in the 'Quick start'.
so that i can access this File Upload by this way Only 'localhost/file_upload'

But how to implement it in myproject so that i can access it by : 'localhost/my_page' & also want to store path for the uploaded file in my own table not in 'uploads' Table.

I am new to use CakePHP, version i am using is 2.3.9